# How to add hours to the original time in dataframe then generate a new date?

Tags: python, pandas

The data in test.csv likes this:

```
device_id,upload_time
id1,2020-06-01 07:46:30+00:00
id2,2020-06-05 16:04:32+00:00
```

I want to remove the `+00:00` in `upload_time` and add 8 hours to `upload_time`  ,then generate a new column `new_upload_time`.

I use this code to do it.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

df = pd.read_csv(r'E:/test.csv',parse_dates=[1], encoding='utf-8')
df['new_upload_time'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['upload_time'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))+timedelta(hours=8)
df.to_csv(r'E:/result.csv', index=False, mode='w', header=True)
```

result.csv:

```
device_id,upload_time,new_upload_time
id1,2020-06-01 07:46:30+00:00,2020-06-01 15:46:30
id2,2020-06-05 16:04:32+00:00,2020-06-06 00:04:32
```

Although I have implemented it, I feel that the code is a bit complicated.

Is there a simple way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the formatting *after* adding 8 hours. You are formatting as a string and then trying to add a number to it. Add the number first and then format as string with `strftime`:

```
df['upload_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['upload_time'])
df['new_upload_time'] = df['upload_time'] + pd.Timedelta(hours=8)
df['new_upload_time'] = df['new_upload_time'].dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
df['upload_time'] = df['upload_time'].dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S') #pass whaetver format that you want to `strftime` here.
df
Out1]: 
  device_id          upload_time      new_upload_time
0       id1  2020/06/01 07:46:30  2020/06/01 15:46:30
1       id2  2020/06/05 16:04:32  2020/06/06 00:04:32
```

You can also specify the `date_format` on export:

```
df['upload_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['upload_time'])
df['new_upload_time'] = df['upload_time'] + pd.Timedelta(hours=8)
df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False, date_format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: Sir,very helpful.

Comment: @CR7 no problem, see the second option in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can localize your timestamp using [`tz_convert`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.tz_convert.html)

so the code should look like:

```
df['new_upload_time'] = df['upload_time'].dt.tz_convert(None) + timedelta(hours=8)
```

this assume that the `dtype` of `upload_time` is `Timestamp`

Note that I changed the answer to use `tz_convert` instead of `tz_localize`

Comment: Very helpful.Thanks!